# Zebra ZQ520 printer, download and use new .CPF font with ZPL language

Tags: printing, fonts, zebra-printers, zpl

problems to print with different fonts on my Zebra ZQ520:
as described in documentation, I've downloaded some new font through the official Zebra Font Downloader program, comic and verdana. After this, I found the new fonts in E: storage area. So the script:

```
^XA^HWE:^XZ
```

give me:

> LIST OF FONT LINKS
>   - DIR E:*.* 
>   * E:COMIC_02.CPF      7359
>   * E:VERDAN02.CPF       163 ....
>   -  66589184 bytes free E: ONBOARD FLASH

and trying to print example string from font downloader program, it print with the installed font with success.
The problem appens if I try to print a label. The printer seems not consider the .CPF files in ZPL commands.
My tests, without success, are:
1) following the procedure indicated in https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7891 , assigning a designator to new font, with the script:

```
^XA^CWQ,E:COMIC_02.CPF^XZ
```

and trying to print something as:

```
^XA^FO50,50^AQN,50,50^FDSAMPLE CoMiC^FS ^XZ
```

seems not working (is it not possible to assign a designator on .CPF files??)
2) (not working too) test, I tryed to print something with the `^A@` command, also without success. Example:

```
^XA^FO50,50^A@N,50,50,E:COMIC_02.CPF^FDSAMPLE CoMiC^FS ^XZ
```

Where is the problem? with printer (updated with the last firmware, V76.19.15Z)?
or ZPL can't print font stored in .CPF files?
or ..??
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ZQ500 supports multiple printing languages. It ships with the PnP string stating that it is a CPCL printer. This tells the Zebra Setup Utility to generate a CPCL compatible font (.CPF). Since you are looking to print using ZPL you need to generate a font compatible with ZPL.

https://km.zebra.com/resources/sites/ZEBRA/content/live/SOLUTIONS/8000/SO8535/en_US/ZebraNet_Bridge_Font_Converting.pdf

This will use a different program to package a .ttf font for the printer. ZPL has support for truetype fonts so you will have better scaling of the font.

The ^CW and ^A@ commands will both work with the ttf font.

Comment: thanks. I found and install the program, the font generator function is accessible, but, on my system, after the dialog of "Licence Agreement" as in page 2 of the manual above mentioned, nothing appens. I try also to generate .TTE and .FNT fonts, but, the application does'nt work.